# How to find out the exact conflicts when apt ask to remove some packages?

Tags: apt

For example, when I was trying to install lxqt on Xenial, I got a message that:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

But I could not figure out why.

--- Edit ---
I figured the conflict by installing aptitude. But still wondering since it is not default installed now, how could I figure this out.

Comment: Can you give the full output of the command as well as the PPAs or software sources you added (if you added some)?

Comment: Due to the full output / PPAs includes some company information, I cannot post them. I posted some info in question.

Comment: Those aren't sufficient. But anyway I'll try to answer your question.

Comment: @Magicloud Redact company names/etc?